# issues with installing digital speech Decoder

Tags: command-line, software-installation

After running into a few problems I'm thinking of trying this next.
The commands at the bottom of the image  where the

```
wget -O itpp-latest.tar.bz2 #http://url#
```

Excuse my paranoia but is this the correct way to go, is there a simpler way to get DSD working. I have tried using git, cmake, but it fails cmake .. + sudo make install. Just doesn't want to work for me.

[image]

I haven't used this yet, but maybe this is what I should be doing?

OK So me being impatient i decided to try it and can say is. make -j crashes my laptop. its the use all cores -j option and my laptop hated it. locked curses and shutdown after a few minutes.

I then used just the make no options and here's the error.

```
[  8%] Building CXX object itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/base/operators.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/base/parser.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/base/random.cpp.o
In file included from /home/plutes/digital_speech/itpp-4.3.1/itpp/base/random_dsfmt.h:40:0,
                 from /home/plutes/digital_speech/itpp-4.3.1/itpp/base/random.h:32,
                 from /home/plutes/digital_speech/itpp-4.3.1/itpp/base/random.cpp:29:
/home/plutes/digital_speech/itpp-4.3.1/itpp/base/random_dsfmt.h: In static member function ‘static void itpp::random_details::DSFMT<MEXP, POS1, SL1, MSK1, MSK2, FIX1_V, FIX2_V, PCV1_V, PCV2_V>::do_recursion(typename itpp::random_details::DSFMT<MEXP, POS1, SL1, MSK1, MSK2, FIX1_V, FIX2_V, PCV1_V, PCV2_V>::Context::w128_t*, typename itpp::random_details::DSFMT<MEXP, POS1, SL1, MSK1, MSK2, FIX1_V, FIX2_V, PCV1_V, PCV2_V>::Context::w128_t*, typename itpp::random_details::DSFMT<MEXP, POS1, SL1, MSK1, MSK2, FIX1_V, FIX2_V, PCV1_V, PCV2_V>::Context::w128_t*, typename itpp::random_details::DSFMT<MEXP, POS1, SL1, MSK1, MSK2, FIX1_V, FIX2_V, PCV1_V, PCV2_V>::Context::w128_t*) [with int MEXP = 19937; int POS1 = 117; int SL1 = 19; long unsigned int MSK1 = 4498102069230399; long unsigned int MSK2 = 4501400546508797; long unsigned int FIX1_V = 10376655713290109737; long unsigned int FIX2_V = 4291106551315987578; long unsigned int PCV1_V = 4432916062321256576; long unsigned int PCV2_V = 1]’:
/home/plutes/digital_speech/itpp-4.3.1/itpp/base/random_dsfmt.h:306:17: error: the last argument must be an 8-bit immediate
     __m128i y = _mm_shuffle_epi32(lung->si, SSE2_SHUFF);
                 ^
itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/build.make:422: recipe for target 'itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/base/random.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/base/random.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: recipe for target 'itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [itpp/CMakeFiles/itpp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using bionic (or equivalent)? In that case there is a g++ v7 compatibility issue with IT++.

https://sourceforge.net/p/itpp/bugs/256/

You can either apply the patch listed in the bug and rebuild or just use the IT++ provided in the repos.

```
apt install libitpp-dev
```

https://github.com/szechyjs/dsd/wiki/Installation#dependency-installation-on-ubuntu-1404-and-newer

Comment: I tell you what mate, I did not thanks, that its a cracking answer. ok so would the apt install libitpp-dev patch the bug?

Comment: Installing libitpp-dev eliminates the need to manually download, compile and install it from source.

Comment: thanks  i had already installed that, I'm really not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: then you can skip the itpp parts of the install instructions. build and install mbelib and dsd now.

Comment: should I after creating the build dir. chmod it in some way at the moment its 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 26 23:02 build. as when i do the cmake it gives errors

Comment: Hot off the press, prebuilt packages for Ubuntu 18.04.
https://github.com/szechyjs/dsd/wiki/Installation#from-ubuntu-ppa